# What does it really mean to write if (TRUE) .... and then if(FALSE) in R

Tags: r

When I type if (TRUE) and then assign a value to a variable and then if (FALSE) and reassign the same variable to something else, and then ask it to print the variable, why does it just print it in the TRUE condition? Like how does it decide to stay in or pick the TRUE condition does it just choose whichever one you type first and then not change?

This is the code I have :

```
if (TRUE) {message<- 'I execute this when true!'}
if (FALSE) {message<- 'I execute this when false!'}
print(message)
```

And when you run it it just prints the first statement, and if you get rid of the first statement it still doesn't print the second one so I'm confused what if(FALSE) is actually telling the computer

I tried:

```
if (TRUE) {message<- 'I execute this when true!'}
if (FALSE) {message<- 'I execute this when false!'}
print(message)
```

I expected it to print the first message and then the second message.

Comment: If you type `if (FALSE) {...}`  whatever you type in the brackets will never run. An `if` statement will only run if you pass in a value or expression that is TRUE. If you pass in the literal FALSE value, there's no way for that to ever be TRUE. Maybe you want an `if (TRUE) {run if true} else {run if false}`. But still you would not typically use TRUE or FALSE, you'd put in something that would evaluate to TRUE or FALSE like `if (x>5)` or something like that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is based on flawed logic.

Comment: @sleepycriter, are you asking how `if (.) { ... } else { ... }` flows _in general_, in the context of parsing the code, in evaluation of components, or something else? If you're learning to program and this is one of your learning steps, that's great! There are a lot of tutorials, _some_ of which may be good, but most of them are good enough to get through these types of questions. (To be clear, this specific question is likely to be mostly universal across most languages, including python, R ruby, bash/shell, etc, so if you find good discussions on `if`/`else`, it should apply in R as well.)

Comment: Keep asking questions, sleepycriter! Some (like this) may be closed for various reasons (please make sure to stay within https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but don't take a closed question as deterrence. You'll learn more through these discussions. I encourage you to stick around immediately after asking a question so these comments can be more of an interactive discussion between you and those who see your question. Good learning!

Answer (score 1):

an example:

```
if(expression){statement}
```

If the expression is TRUE, the statement gets executed. But if it’s FALSE, nothing happens.
If you use variables for that like

```
myexpression = TRUE;
if(myexpression){statement}
```

it works the same. If it is true, the statement gets executed, if not, nothing happens.
Instead of a variable you used TRUE or FALSE. So your expression is TRUE in the first case and FALSE in the second case.